# Getting "specified cast is not valid" when trying to display last logon for users in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

In my win forms app I have a list view which displays the user's First Name, Last Name and Username.  I am now trying to add the last logon date for that user by using the below code:

```
lstActiveDirectory.Columns.Add("First Name", 150);
lstActiveDirectory.Columns.Add("Last Name", 150);
lstActiveDirectory.Columns.Add("Username", 150);
lstActiveDirectory.Columns.Add("Last Logon", 150);


DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
long lastLogon = (long)de.Properties["lastLogon"][0];
DateTime dtLastLogon = DateTime.FromFileTime(lastLogon);
string[] arr = new string[4];
ListViewItem itm;

//Add first item
arr[0] = (string)de.Properties["givenName"].Value;
arr[1] = (string)de.Properties["sn"].Value;
arr[2] = (string)de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value;
arr[3] = dtLastLogon.ToString();
itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
lstActiveDirectory.Items.Add(itm);
```

But seem to be getting the error `specified cast is not valid`.  I think I not displaying the `Last Logon` correctly as a string?

What do I need to do to get the last logon to display correctly?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In what line are you getting the error? I see several castings... What does `de.Properties["lastLogon"][0].GetType()` return?

Comment: step through your code and check on every single property its actual type, e.g. by hovering the mouse over `de.Properties[...].Value`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured it out with the below code:

```
lstActiveDirectory.Clear();
lstActiveDirectory.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
lstActiveDirectory.Columns.Add("First Name", 150);
lstActiveDirectory.Columns.Add("Last Name", 150);
lstActiveDirectory.Columns.Add("Last Logon", 150);
lstActiveDirectory.Columns.Add("Last Password Reset", 150);

PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, strADPath, strUsername, strPassword);
UserPrincipal usr = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
usr.AdvancedSearchFilter.LastLogonTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90), MatchType.GreaterThan);
PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(usr);
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = ps.FindAll();

  foreach (UserPrincipal u in results)
     {
       string[] arr = new string[4];
       ListViewItem itm;

       //Add first item
       arr[0] = u.DisplayName;
       arr[1] = u.SamAccountName;
       arr[2] = u.LastLogon.ToString();
       arr[3] = u.LastPasswordSet.ToString();
       itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
       lstActiveDirectory.Items.Add(itm);
     }
  }
```

The only problem I have now is that it is not displaying the actual logon date and time. But works at the moment

At the moment it displays the `LastLogonTimestamp` instead of the `LastLogon` as per attribute editor in AD.

Thanks